# Avoiding other users, except the property owner accessing some specific urls in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Hello I have a laravel application with stripe payment gateway.

```
http://test.site/checkout/13
```

this is the url format where my users been asked to enter their card details and complete the payment.

This 13 is the unique appid which is generating from the earlier step of the system (Users can create an app and each app has an appid)

Now, My issue is any logged in user can access this url and even do a payment.

How can I avoid this situation, how to enable this url only for the app owner and how to show an error message if some other user try to access this url?

Comment: check the relation of  the id with the logged in user, if that id is posted,submitted by the logged in user then proceed further otherwise redirect with error message

Answer (score 0):

You can check on your controller like that :

```
 public function edit(Request $request)
{
   // If user is not property owner
   if ($user->propertyOwner() == 0) {
      return abort(401); // user will go to 403 page
   }

   // If user is property owner
   // Do what you want
}
```

Comment: no the issue is only the property owner should be able to login in to that url, appid 14 owner should not be able to access appid 13, then 14 user can pay for 13 app.. that's wht i'm asking